# How to convert a string to list in python， the string is read from a text file

Tags: python, string, list

I save some data in an out.txt file, and want to read them as list for some calculation,
I use this code for read

```
f = open('peer5/out12.txt', 'r')
s = f.readlines()
for line in s:
    result = line
    print result
f.close()
```

Now I get the result as

> [{u'apeer': 4, u'bisSucc': 0}, {u'apeer': 3, u'bisSucc': 0}, {u'apeer': 2, u'bisSucc': 0}]

this is a string, I want convert them into a list,but the form will same as the result, then I tried the code

`result1 = map(list,line)` and `result1 = map(list,line.split(","))`

but the result1 looks like :

> [['['], ['{'], ['u'], ["'"], ['a'], ['p'], ['e'], ['e'], ['r'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['4'], [','], [' '], ['u'], ["'"], ['b'], ['i'], ['s'], ['S'], ['u'], ['c'], ['c'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['0'], ['}'], [','], [' '], ['{'], ['u'], ["'"], ['a'], ['p'], ['e'], ['e'], ['r'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['3'], [','], [' '], ['u'], ["'"], ['b'], ['i'], ['s'], ['S'], ['u'], ['c'], ['c'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['0'], ['}'], [','], [' '], ['{'], ['u'], ["'"], ['a'], ['p'], ['e'], ['e'], ['r'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['2'], [','], [' '], ['u'], ["'"], ['b'], ['i'], ['s'], ['S'], ['u'], ['c'], ['c'], ["'"], [':'], [' '], ['0'], ['}'], [']'], ['\n']]

Can I convert the string to list, but the form for the data will not change?

Comment: Please specify your required output.

Comment: What does your input file look like? And I'm pretty sure that your example code and output don't match, because your first output has dictionaries, but none are created in your code.

Comment: Kindly clarify your requirements more clearly because too many things seems to have been messed up here. If you are looking to how convert a string to a list then use list() method, like list(s) where s is a string.

Answer (score 0):

But, can you tell us an example of what you really want?

For example you have a list of dictionaries

```
[{u'apeer': 4, u'bisSucc': 0}, {u'apeer': 3, u'bisSucc': 0}, {u'apeer': 2, u'bisSucc': 0}]
```

Each line is a dict, do you want to transform each dict to a list?

```
[[u'apeer', u'bisSucc'], [u'apeer', u'bisSucc'], [u'apeer', u'bisSucc']]
```

If so, you can use a list comprehension:

```
[list (x) for x in result]
```

Answer (score -1):

**Example**

```
list = []
path = 'c:/users/-e/my documents/text.txt'

with open(path, 'r') as file:

    for line in file:
        list.append(line)

    print(list)
```

Comment: You can simply say `with open(path, 'r') as file: list = file.readlines()  print(list)`

Comment: Whoever down voted I would welcome justification. With respect to @zondo, Yes you can but you will get a string on the output as opposed to a list which is requested in OP

Comment: If I had said `file.read()`, then yes it would be a string, but `file.readlines()` returns a list.  I downvoted because I did not think that your answer was relevant.  If the OP just wanted a list of the lines of the file, he would have stopped at the `s = file.readlines()` line.  I believe that what he wants is to create a list based on the contents of each line.  If I see a reason to change my mind, I will un-downvote.